# How to generate RSA public key using exponent (e) and modulus (n) to verify the signature of a json web token?

Tags: node.js, jwt, rsa, public-key, jwk

My goal is to verify my id_token in JSON Web Token (JWT) format using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) verify method, which requires a public key as the second argument. My web application is a node js application.

According to [Ping ID's documentation](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/developer/page/bly1601508087776.html), I am supposed to generate the RSA public key using the exponent(e) and modulus(n). Here is an example that is applicable for my id_token:

```
   {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "IlOPtWXUcpiPttmr-K7DmehzeRM",
    "use": "enc",
    "n": "qv2XCvfUfW0bG547B1xieE0-GN8xLuCdzGcIWsYMP-fn1vR2ptR7XOp_kW-etlxSDT2MVyzdXbG9eQCgeBk-Ajgbyn4AaFScJt9ibGyE-5hUvkSJRTP-jlJjlPniYsKcjEY3C-QzyRcEIHoOHOEuevIFwVvKNRgEVYyx3CmkmIXcfw35R1tORNjCec_NA6dawx_LPpS0endjNz2m_iijLquKenrsKSKVnBprfVtBh_myuNQD5CfhBnzZRmAUfr0PoVMDBb0r_rWaV1Q64zQWSeCql7CSWq4U8RNhogd0eCZOOv45plIUwoxkdNg0Rzkp-OEtKRLaHonJ_OZ_sxa8-w",
    "e": "AQAB"
    },
```

The question is, how do I generate the public key using these values? Is there a node js library that does this?

I am new to cryptography, so pardon my beginner's question.

Comment: what you got there is a JWK(JSON Web Key). You can use [Jose](https://github.com/panva/jose), which ha a function [`parseJWK`](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/functions/jwk_parse.parsejwk.md#readme) to create a public key for verification.

Answer (score 6):

You can use node's Crypto module to easily convert a jwk to a public key(pem), without using external dependencies.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

let publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey({
  key: {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "IlOPtWXUcpiPttmr-K7DmehzeRM",
    "n": "qv2XCvfUfW0bG547B1xieE0-GN8xLuCdzGcIWsYMP-fn1vR2ptR7XOp_kW-etlxSDT2MVyzdXbG9eQCgeBk-Ajgbyn4AaFScJt9ibGyE-5hUvkSJRTP-jlJjlPniYsKcjEY3C-QzyRcEIHoOHOEuevIFwVvKNRgEVYyx3CmkmIXcfw35R1tORNjCec_NA6dawx_LPpS0endjNz2m_iijLquKenrsKSKVnBprfVtBh_myuNQD5CfhBnzZRmAUfr0PoVMDBb0r_rWaV1Q64zQWSeCql7CSWq4U8RNhogd0eCZOOv45plIUwoxkdNg0Rzkp-OEtKRLaHonJ_OZ_sxa8-w",
    "e": "AQAB"
  }, format: 'jwk'
});
```

You can then use this to verify the jwt.

```
let pem = publicKey.export({ type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' });
jwt.verify(jwtToken, pem, (err, decoded) => {
})
```

Comment: An example of this was surprisingly hard to find. I have tested this with my set of JWKS and token, it works as expected. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `jsonwebtoken`'s `verify` method, then you can do it by converting your `jwk` into a pem string, for example, using `jwt-to-pem`. Using the example on the [package's website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwk-to-pem), it goes like this:

First you install

```
npm i jwt-to-pem -D
```

And then you convert and use

```js
import * as jwtToPem from 'jwt-to-pem';
import {verify} from 'jsonwebtoken';

let jwk = {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "IlOPtWXUcpiPttmr-K7DmehzeRM",
    "use": "enc",
    "n": "qv2XCvfUfW0bG547B1...",
    "e": "AQAB"
};

let pem_str = jwtToPem(jwk);

//Finally, verification for some token
verify(id_token, pem_str);
```

And that's all. I saw in `node`'s `crypto` documentation that you should be able to do it without external dependencies, but I didn't manage it!